# Update text in StatusBar in wpf using C#

Tags: wpf, statusbar

I have a TextBox in StatusBar in wpf which I want to update.

I have a list of files in ListBox. On each file I would be doing some operation by calling say method ProcessFile(). So whenever the file processing is completed I want to show that file's name in the StatusBar text.

I have tried something like this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        statusBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(TimeConsumingMethod), frame);
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
        statusBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object TimeConsumingMethod(Object arg)
    {
        ((DispatcherFrame)arg).Continue = false;
        
        foreach (string fileName in destinationFilesList.Items)
        {
            txtStatus.Text = fileName.ToString();
            //Assume that each process takes some time to complete
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But I can only see the last file's name in the StatusBar. What's wrong with the code? How can I correct it?

Answer (score 4):

There's more ways to do this.

**Set content directly from code**
You need give name to the `TextBox` so that you can access it's content:

XAML

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" />
```

C#

```
...
ProcessFile(someFileName);
myTextBox.Text = someFileName;
```

**Use data binding**
You need to create some object and set it as `DataContext` to the `TextBox` or some WPF element that contain that text box (status bar, window, ...).

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ProcessedFileName}" />
```

C#

```
public MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string ProcessedFileName {get; set;} 

    public void ProcessFile(string someFileName)
    {
       // Processing file code here

       // When done processing, set file name to property
       ProcessedFileName = someFileName;
       OnPropertyChanged("ProcessedFileName");
    } 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

For more information on data binding see [**Data Binding Overview**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)

Comment: why shall i create a spearate class if it can only be done with few lines using Dispatcher?

Comment: See article "Data Binding Overview" for explanation. Link is above at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using a ViewModel, i would define a Property "ProcessedFile" in your ViewModel and bind the Textbox of your StatusBar to the Property.

Every time you processed a file i would set the Property "ProcessedFile" to the name of the file.

Here´s some code for the ViewModel.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private string _processedFile;
    public string ProcessedFile {
        get {
            return _processedFile;
        }
        set {

            if (_processedFile != value) {
                _processedFile = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null) {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ProcessedFile"));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion

    public void ProcessFile() {
       // Process the file
       ProcessedFile = //Set the Property to the processed file
    }
}
```

Heres the XAML to bind the TextBox to the Property. (I assume that the ViewModel is set as DataContext for the TextBox)

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ProcessedFile, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```